# How to organize and break down services in Go project directory structure?

Tags: go, directory-structure

Say I have a service that communicates with Github via the API to create and modify repositories.

The list of functions might look something like below.

Each request made to the API has several moving parts so I split it up into multiple functions

```
// github_service.go

package main

// :show (GET) functions
func findGithubRepository(...)
func findGithubRepositoryRequestBuilder(...)
func findGithubRepositoryUrl(...)

// :create (POST) functions
func createGithubRepository(...)
func createGithubRepositoryPayload(...)
func createGithubRepositoryRequestBuilder(...)
func createGithubRepositoryUrl(...)

// :update (PUT) functions
func updateGithubRepository(...)
func updateGithubRepositoryPayload(...)
func updateGithubRepositoryRequestBuilder(...)
func updateGithubRepositoryUrl(...)


// Helpers used by above functions
func queryGithub(...)
func GithubHostName(...)
```

This layout has 2 problems -

1. Everything is in one big file called `github_service.go` and I'm not sure how to split it up. **Should it be in smaller sub-directories like `services/github/update_service.go`?** In general how does one organize services like this in a simple project (e.g. a command line utility)
2. Since all this is in the same Go package the name has to be unique. So I have namespace all the functions with the action and the context (e.g. `findGithubRepositoryUrl()` instead of `url()`). **Should each be under a separate package?**. But then how would they share common helpers?

Thanks!

Comment: Start with one package and once you identify a coherent, closed subpart: Move that to its own package.

Answer (score 1):

There's multiple solutions to this.

- You can keep all the functions in the same package, in different files. You have to use verbose names.
- You can create a struct for each resource, and define a set of functions for that:

```
type GithubRepository struct  {}

func (g GithubRepository) find() {}
func (g GithubRepository) create() {}

type GithubRepositoryPayload struct {}

func (g GithubRepositoryPayload) find() {}
func (g GithubRepositoryPayload) create() {}
...
```

This may also give handlers a way to access to common functionality or variables. You can create a base struct with those and embed it into all of the handler structs.

Comment: Thanks! The struct approach seems like a way to mimic traditional classes provided by other OOP languages like ruby and python, right?

Comment: It is a more OO-like approach with the main point being namespace isolation and the ability to pass resource-specific common services to each implementation. I use this often, and keep resource-specific backend services in the struct for the handler.

Comment: Thanks! Would it be possible to group everything by `find()` instead of by resource (`Payload`, base, etc...)? And would you happen to have a working example of this you could share? Appreciate the insight.

Comment: You can group it like that, sometimes it makes sense while writing it. Think about how you'll find what you need a month later when you're reading it. I am not aware of an open example that uses this kind of structure. It looks more suitable for a cli, like 'kubectl get pods'.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can organize your project with this [structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtT1e.png)
2. - If the files are in same package the name of functions must be diferent.
   - You can create package called 'helpers' and use from any other package. (Dont forget configure GOPATH enviroment variable)

I have created an [repository](https://github.com/Nikola43/go-basic-structure) with this structure, you can clone it and use it as a template. I hope I've helped :)

Answer (score 0):

> For making the project simple and minimize the multiple imports of files keep all files under same package with different file names. Example (assume for testService):

```
repoName: testService
folder structure
  1.testService(Dir)
    2.routes.go
    2.commons.go
    2.handler.go
    2.models.go
    2.utils.go
  1.main.go
  1.Dockerfile
```

> here numbers 1 represents that they are on same level and 2 represents files under service directory